# Codeception Recorder

Tags: php, codeception

I'm new to Codeception and really liking the idea of the Recorder released as part of 2.1 but I'm really struggling getting it to work.

My acceptance.suite.yml looks like:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://whatever/
            browser: phantomjs
            window_size: 1024x768
        - \Helper\Acceptance

extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\Recorder
    config:
        Codeception\Extension\Recorder:
            delete_successful: false
```

The PhantomJS stuff is working nicely but it looks like the Recorder extension isn't being loaded as nothing ever appears in the `_output` folder.

I've seen in places that I should include something in `_bootstrap.php` but given that Recorder is part of the core, then I wouldn't know what to include there.

I'm probably doing something really silly but the documentation on this is rather patchy at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it works at suite level, put it in your app wide codeception.yml

```
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
        - Codeception\Extension\Recorder
    config:
        Codeception\Extension\Recorder:
            delete_successful: false
```

Comment: Thanks @Kiel, it was as simple as that.

Comment: It should work at the suite level, the docs say `Add this to the list of enabled extensions in codeception.yml or acceptance.suite.yml`